# how to validate selectize dropdownlist in mvc 4.5?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working with `mvc` in `framework-4.5`. In all other fields validation is working properly, but i am finding it difficult for selectize dropdownlist. Validation is working properly in simple dropdownlist also.
I tried to show message using field-validation-error and input-validation-error but not getting any success. Here are some changes i made in `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

```
function onError(error, inputElement) {  // 'this' is the form element

    var container = $(this).find("[data-valmsg-for='" + escapeAttributeValue(inputElement[0].name) + "']"),
    replaceAttrValue = container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"),
    replace = replaceAttrValue ? $.parseJSON(replaceAttrValue) !== false : null;
    container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
    error.data("unobtrusiveContainer", container);
    if (replace) {
        container.empty();
        error.removeClass("input-validation-error-+-").appendTo(container);
    }
    else {
        error.hide();
    }
    //For Validation Toggel Start 
    debugger;

    if ($(inputElement).parent().hasClass("selectize-input")) {
        $(inputElement).parent().parent().parent().addClass("md-input-danger");
        var container = error.data("unobtrusiveContainer");
        container.removeClass("field-validation-valid").addClass("field-validation-error");
    }       
}
```

I did lots of research for this but i didn't get any proper solution.

please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

add below JQuery code in document ready to validate your selectize dropdown

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ':hidden:not([class~=selectized]),:hidden > .selectized, .selectize-control .selectize-input input'
});
```